# How to fix random tkinter cget error when not using cget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to make a video player in Tkinter, but run into a problem when using threads

The error is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Nanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nanny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1643, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I am not using cget, or any "get" functions inside the thread at all.

The weird part is that, the error still persists even when theres nothing inside the thread function

My thread starting code is:

```
videoLabel = tk.Label(frame)
videoLabel.pack()
thread = threading.Thread(target=stream, args=(videoLabel))
thread.start()
frame.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3.8 and Tkinter libraries.

Comment: The reason is `tkinter` does not support multithreading.

Comment: Also note that `args` needs to be a tuple:  `args=(videoLabel,)`.

Comment: Since tkinter doesn't support multithreading, what can I do?

Comment: You can have multiple threads, but only one can make use of `tkinter`. A common workaround is to pass messages between the threads using a `Queue` and having the GUI thread periodically check it for new messages for the other thread.